# prove that $f^{-1}((0,0))$ is infinite

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, continuity, extreme-value-theorem

> Let $A = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x = 0 \text{ or } y = 0\}$ equipped with the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to A$ be a surjective and continuous map. Prove that $f^{-1}((0,0))$ is infinite.

Since $f$ is continuous, by the EVT, it has a maximum and minimum on any compact subset of $A.$ For a contradiction, assume that $f^{-1}((0,0))$ is bounded and let a and b be the minimum and maximum of $f^{-1}((0,0))$. It could be useful to determine what $f((-\infty, a)), f([a,b]), f((b,\infty))$ could be. I know that continuous functions map connected sets to connected sets, so the above sets are all connected. Also, I know that continuous functions map compact sets to compact sets. How can one get a contradiction from here?

Comment: I think with problems like this it can help a lot to first convince yourself, informally, that the result is true. Have you done this already? Could you say a little about this - ie how would you informally justify this fact, and what goes wrong when you try and make your informal justification rigorous? PS: perhaps it helps to look at a simpler example first. Can you prove that if $f: [0, \infty) \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(0)$ is infinite?

Comment: FWIW: my informal justification would be "suppose two ants parachute into $A$ at time $0$, and walk around $A$ until time $\infty$, visiting each point at least once. At time $t$, they can't have covered the entirety of any of the arms of $A$ yet. So at least one has to cross back over to the other arms at some later time." Writing $B_n$ for the direct sum of $n$ copies of $[0, \infty)$ and $A_n$ for the wedge sum of $n$ copies of $[0,\infty)$ joined at $0$ (so $A=A_4$), this shows the result for maps $B_2 \to A_4$ (from which $\Bbb R \to A_4$ follows), and suggests a natural generalisation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you are along the right lines. $f[[a, b]]$ is a compact and hence bounded subset of $A$, while $f[(-\infty, a)]$ and $f[(b, \infty)]$ are connected subsets of $A \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. So $A$ is the union of a bounded subset and two sets both of which are contained in one of the four connected components of $A \setminus \{(0, 0)\}$. As each of those connected components is unbounded, such a union cannot be all of $A$.